# How to use dynamic databases in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd, lis, prolog-assert

I have written the following program, which calculates the longest non-decreasing sub-sequence of input array.

The sub-program to find the longest list from the list of lists is taken from stackoverflow ([How do I find the longest list in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660152/how-do-i-find-the-longest-list-in-a-list-of-lists)) itself.

```
:- dynamic lns/2.
:- retractall(lns(_, _)).

lns([], []).
lns([X|_], [X]).
lns([X|Xs], [X, Y|Ls]) :-
    lns(Xs, [Y|Ls]),
    X < Y,
    asserta(lns([X|Xs], [X, Y|Ls])).
lns([_|Xs], [Y|Ls]) :-
    lns(Xs, [Y|Ls]).

% Find the longest list from the list of lists.
lengths([], []).
lengths([H|T], [LH|LengthsT]) :-
    length(H, LH),
    lengths(T, LengthsT).

lengthLongest(ListOfLists, Max) :-
    lengths(ListOfLists, Lengths),
    max_list(Lengths, Max).

longestList(ListOfLists, Longest) :-
    lengthLongest(ListOfLists, Len),
    member(Longest, ListOfLists),
    length(Longest, Len).

optimum_solution(List, Ans) :-
    setof(A, lns(List, A), P),
    longestList(P, Ans), 
    !.
```

I have used the Prolog dynamic database for memoization purpose. 
Though the program with database runs slower than the program without database. Below are the comparative times between two runs.

```
?- time(optimum_solution([0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9], Ans)).
% 53,397 inferences, 0.088 CPU in 0.088 seconds (100% CPU, 609577 Lips)
Ans = [0, 2, 6, 9]. %% With database

?- time(optimum_solution([0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9], Ans)).
% 4,097 inferences, 0.002 CPU in 0.002 seconds (100% CPU, 2322004 Lips)
Ans = [0, 2, 6, 9]. %% Without database. commented out the database usage.
```

I would like to know if I am using the dynamic database correctly. Thanks!

Comment: You really should link to the question or answer from which you got your code.

Comment: Are you sure that you are doing the timing correctly? Is it at all possible that this second run you show is actually using the memoized facts?

Comment: @DanielLyons Since `asserta` is used (not `assertz`) the longest subsequence found so far will be matched first. Since the lists will be unified in the head of the predicate, there is no explicit (native Prolog) traversal, which is why it is not entirely bad as an approach (the traversal still happens of course, but much more efficient). I would nevertheless like to see a link to the source of this code.

Comment: @Boris. I have added link to the source where I took the solution to find the longest list from list of lists. I also verified again and I can see that I am doing the timing correctly.

Comment: @Daniel. I could not think of O(n) solution to this problem. If you know one, could you please share?

Comment: @user114754. There **is** no O(n) algorithm for this problem. For more on this, look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence .

Comment: @user114754. Want some more clpfd-based approaches? I got at least two others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that as you are traversing the list building subsequences, you need to consider only prior subsequences whose last value is less than the value you have in-hand. The problem is that Prolog's first-argument indexing is doing an equality check, not a less-than check. So Prolog will have to traverse the entire store of `lns/2`, unifying the first parameter with a value so you can check to see if it's less and then backtracking to get the next.

Comment: What about tie situations? Consider: First, `longest_increasing_subsequence([0,8,4,12,2,10,6,14,1],[0,2,6,14])` succeeds. Let's append `9` to above list! Now, `longest_increasing_subsequence([0,8,4,12,2,10,6,14,1,9],[0,2,6,9])` succeeds, but `longest_increasing_subsequence([0,8,4,12,2,10,6,14,1,9],[0,2,6,14])` fails even though `[0,2,6,14]` **still is** optimal.

Comment: @Daniel. Your explanation about first-argument indexing explains why dynamic database usage is slowing down the program instead of reducing the run time. Thanks. 
Though as 'repeat' pointed out, solution you provided fails in few situations. Mine program still works but is slower.

Answer (score 2):

[Earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35232831/4609915), we presented a *concise* solution based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).
Now we aim at generality *and* efficiency!

```
:- use_module([library(clpfd), library(lists)]).

list_long_nondecreasing_subseq(Zs, Xs) :-
   minimum(Min, Zs),
   append(_, Suffix, Zs),
   same_length(Suffix, Xs),
   zs_subseq_taken0(Zs, Xs, Min).

zs_subseq_taken0([], [], _).
zs_subseq_taken0([E|Es], [E|Xs], E0) :-
   E0 #=< E,
   zs_subseq_taken0(Es, Xs, E).
zs_subseq_taken0([E|Es], Xs, E0) :-
   zs_subseq_taken0_min0_max0(Es, Xs, E0, E, E).

zs_subseq_taken0_min0_max0([], [], E0, _, Max) :-
   Max #< E0.
zs_subseq_taken0_min0_max0([E|Es], [E|Xs], E0, Min, Max) :-
   E0 #=< E,
   E0 #> Min #\/ Min #> E,
   E0 #> Max #\/ Max #> E,
   zs_subseq_taken0(Es, Xs, E).
zs_subseq_taken0_min0_max0([E|Es], Xs, E0, Min0, Max0) :-
   Min #= min(Min0,E),
   Max #= max(Max0,E),
   zs_subseq_taken0_min0_max0(Es, Xs, E0, Min, Max).
```

Sample query using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2 (with pretty-printed answer sequence):

```
?- list_long_nondecreasing_subseq([0,8,4,12,2,10,6,14,1,9], Xs).
   Xs = [0,8,12,14]
;  Xs = [0,8,10,14]
;  Xs = [0,4,12,14]
;  Xs = [0,4,10,14]
;  Xs = [0,4, 6,14]
;  Xs = [0,4, 6, 9]
;  Xs = [0,2,10,14]
;  Xs = [0,2, 6,14]
;  Xs = [0,2, 6, 9]
;  Xs = [0,8,9]
;  Xs = [0,4,9]
;  Xs = [0,2,9]
;  Xs = [0,1,9]
;  false.
```

Note that the answer sequence of `list_long_nondecreasing_subseq/2` 
may be *a lot* smaller than the one given by [`list_nondecreasing_subseq/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35232831/4609915).

Above list `[0,8,4,12,2,10,6,14,1,9]` has **9** non-descending subsequences of length *4*—all are "returned" by both `list_nondecreasing_subseq/2` *and* 
`list_long_nondecreasing_subseq/2`.

The respective answer sequence sizes, however, differ considerably: (65+9=**74**) vs (4+9=**13**).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** 
In this answer we implement a very general approach based on [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_nondecreasing_subseq(Zs, Xs) :-
   append(_, Suffix, Zs),
   same_length(Suffix, Xs),
   chain(Xs, #=<),
   list_subseq(Zs, Xs).                % a.k.a. subset/2 by @gusbro
```

Sample query using SWI-Prolog 7.3.16:

```
?- list_nondecreasing_subseq([0,8,4,12,2,10,6,14,1,9], Zs).
   Zs = [0,8,12,14]
;  Zs = [0,8,10,14]
;  Zs = [0,4,12,14]
;  Zs = [0,4,10,14]
;  Zs = [0,4,6,14]
;  Zs = [0,4,6,9]
;  Zs = [0,2,10,14]
;  Zs = [0,2,6,14]
;  Zs = [0,2,6,9]
;  Zs = [0,8,12]
...
;  Zs = [9]
;  Zs = []
;  false.
```

Note the particular order of the answer sequence!
The longest lists come first, followed by the lists a little smaller ... all the way down to singleton lists, and the empty list.

Comment: Just 4 lines...!! (+ gusbro solution for subset/2). Very elegant and concise...!! Thank you.

Comment: @user114754. Thx for appreciating! With some Prolog systems, `list_subseq/2` is available out-of-the-box as a library predicate: [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/), for instance, provides [`subseq0/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dlists.html).

Comment: "I would like to know if I am using the dynamic database correctly. Thanks!"—the question.

Comment: @DanielLyons. The OP has answered *that* question, don't you agree? "Do I get correct answer(s)?" Yes. "Am I saving memory?" No. "Does it run faster?" No.

Answer (score 0):

Keeps getting better!
In this answer we present `list_long_nondecreasing_subseq__NEW/2`, a drop-in replacement of `list_long_nondecreasing_subseq/2`—presented [in this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35259679/4609915).

Let's cut to the chase and define `list_long_nondecreasing_subseq__NEW/2`!

```
:- use_module([library(clpfd), library(lists), library(random), library(between)]).

list_long_nondecreasing_subseq__NEW(Zs, Xs) :-
   minimum(Min, Zs),
   append(Prefix, Suffix, Zs),
   same_length(Suffix, Xs),
   zs_skipped_subseq_taken0(Zs, Prefix, Xs, Min).

zs_skipped_subseq_taken0([], _, [], _).
zs_skipped_subseq_taken0([E|Es], Ps, [E|Xs], E0) :-
   E0 #=< E,
   zs_skipped_subseq_taken0(Es, Ps, Xs, E).
zs_skipped_subseq_taken0([E|Es], [_|Ps], Xs, E0) :-
   zs_skipped_subseq_taken0_min0_max0(Es, Ps, Xs, E0, E, E).

zs_skipped_subseq_taken0_min0_max0([], _, [], E0, _, Max) :-
   Max #< E0.
zs_skipped_subseq_taken0_min0_max0([E|Es], Ps, [E|Xs], E0, Min, Max) :-
   E0 #=< E,
   E0 #> Min #\/ Min #> E,
   E0 #> Max #\/ Max #> E,
   zs_skipped_subseq_taken0(Es, Ps, Xs, E).
zs_skipped_subseq_taken0_min0_max0([E|Es], [_|Ps], Xs, E0, Min0, Max0) :-
   Min #= min(Min0,E),
   Max #= max(Max0,E),
   zs_skipped_subseq_taken0_min0_max0(Es, Ps, Xs, E0, Min, Max).
```

So ... does it still work as before? Let's run some tests and compare the answer sequences:

```
| ?- setrand(random(29251,13760,3736,425005073)),
     between(7, 23, N), 
     nl,
     write(n=N),
     write(' '),
     length(Zs, N),
     between(1, 10, _),
     maplist(random(1,N), Zs),
     findall(Xs1, list_long_nondecreasing_subseq(     Zs,Xs1), Xss1),
     findall(Xs2, list_long_nondecreasing_subseq__NEW(Zs,Xs2), Xss2),
     ( Xss1 == Xss2 -> true ; throw(up) ),
     length(Xss2,L),
     write({L}),
     false.

n=7 {3}{8}{3}{7}{2}{5}{4}{4}{8}{4}
n=8 {9}{9}{9}{8}{4}{4}{7}{5}{6}{9}
n=9 {9}{8}{5}{7}{10}{7}{9}{4}{5}{4}
n=10 {7}{12}{7}{14}{13}{19}{13}{17}{10}{7}
n=11 {14}{17}{7}{9}{17}{21}{14}{10}{10}{21}
n=12 {25}{18}{20}{10}{32}{35}{7}{30}{15}{11}
n=13 {37}{19}{18}{22}{20}{14}{10}{11}{8}{14}
n=14 {27}{9}{18}{10}{20}{29}{69}{28}{10}{33}
n=15 {17}{24}{13}{26}{32}{14}{22}{28}{32}{41}
n=16 {41}{55}{35}{73}{44}{22}{46}{47}{26}{23}
n=17 {54}{43}{38}{110}{50}{33}{48}{64}{33}{56}
n=18 {172}{29}{79}{36}{32}{99}{55}{48}{83}{37}
n=19 {225}{83}{119}{61}{27}{67}{48}{65}{90}{96}
n=20 {58}{121}{206}{169}{111}{66}{233}{57}{110}{146}
n=21 {44}{108}{89}{99}{149}{148}{92}{76}{53}{47}
n=22 {107}{137}{221}{79}{172}{156}{184}{78}{162}{112}
n=23 {163}{62}{76}{192}{133}{372}{101}{290}{84}{378}
no
```

All answer sequences were **exactly** identical! ... So, how about runtimes?

Let's run some more queries using SICStus Prolog 4.3.2 and pretty-print the answers!

```
?- member(N, [15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50]),
   length(Zs, N),
   _NN #= N*N,
   maplist(random(1,_NN), Zs),
   call_time(once(list_long_nondecreasing_subseq(     Zs, Xs )), T1),
   call_time(once(list_long_nondecreasing_subseq__NEW(Zs,_Xs2)), T2),
   Xs == _Xs2,
   length(Xs,L).
N = 15, L =  4, T1 =    20, T2 =    0, Zs = [224,150,161,104,134,43,9,111,76,125,50,68,202,178,148], Xs = [104,111,125,202] ;
N = 20, L =  6, T1 =    60, T2 =   10, Zs = [71,203,332,366,350,19,241,88,370,100,288,199,235,343,181,90,63,149,215,285], Xs = [71,88,100,199,235,343] ;
N = 25, L =  7, T1 =   210, T2 =   20, Zs = [62,411,250,222,141,292,276,94,548,322,13,317,68,488,137,33,80,167,101,475,475,429,217,25,477], Xs = [62,250,292,322,475,475,477] ;
N = 30, L = 10, T1 =   870, T2 =   30, Zs = [67,175,818,741,669,312,99,23,478,696,63,793,280,364,677,254,530,216,291,660,218,664,476,556,678,626,75,834,578,850], Xs = [67,175,312,478,530,660,664,678,834,850] ;
N = 35, L =  7, T1 =   960, T2 =  120, Zs = [675,763,1141,1070,299,650,1061,1184,512,905,139,719,844,8,1186,1006,400,690,29,791,308,1180,819,331,482,982,81,574,1220,431,416,357,1139,636,591], Xs = [299,650,719,844,1006,1180,1220] ;
N = 40, L =  9, T1 =  5400, T2 =  470, Zs = [958,1047,132,1381,22,991,701,1548,470,1281,358,32,605,1270,692,1020,350,794,1451,11,985,1196,504,1367,618,1064,961,463,736,907,1103,719,1385,1026,935,489,1053,380,637,51], Xs = [132,470,605,692,794,985,1196,1367,1385] ;
N = 45, L = 10, T1 = 16570, T2 = 1580, Zs = [1452,171,442,1751,160,1046,470,450,1245,971,1574,901,1613,1214,1849,1805,341,34,1923,698,156,1696,717,1708,1814,1548,463,421,1584,190,1195,1563,1772,1639,712,693,1848,1531,250,783,1654,1732,1333,717,1322], Xs = [171,442,1046,1245,1574,1613,1696,1708,1814,1848] ;
N = 50, L = 11, T1 = 17800, T2 = 1360, Zs = [2478,2011,2411,1127,1719,1286,1081,2042,1166,86,355,894,190,7,1973,1912,753,1411,1082,70,2142,417,1609,1649,2329,2477,1324,37,1781,1897,2415,1018,183,2422,1619,1446,1461,271,56,2399,1681,267,977,826,2145,2318,2391,137,55,1995], Xs = [86,355,894,1411,1609,1649,1781,1897,2145,2318,2391] ;
false.
```

Of course, the [baroque](http://www.hacker-dictionary.com/terms/baroque) approach shown in this answer simply cannot compete with "serious" [suitable algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6129682/4609915) for determining the [lis](/questions/tagged/lis)—still, getting 10X speedup always feels good:)